# PHP and MySQL Subquery with where id in()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
  $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.id as cid, c.name as catname, p.title as ptitle,"
  . "\n CONCAT(u.first,' ',u.last) as user," 
  . "\n (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags) as tagnames FROM tagtable WHERE id IN (p.tagids))" 
  . "\n FROM posts as p" 
  . "\n LEFT JOIN categories as c ON c.id = a.cid" 
  . "\n LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.uid" 
  . "\n WHERE a.active = 1 LIMIT 1";
```

The only issue I'm having is with subquery

`"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags)..."`

For some reason it does not produce any results. I'm expecting to get tag names row as

> "lorem, ipsum, dolores, ..."

Field *tag-ids* is in `1,2,3` format.

Comment: how did you get p.tagids is in 1,2,3 format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tagids are of the format '1,2,3' rather make use of

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings.

So, something like

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,p.tagids) > 0
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3bb54/1)